# Winston Http Transport not working inside MochaJS custom Reporter

Tags: mocha.js, winston, datadog

I'm trying to log errors using Http Transport and it's not working properly inside the custom report EVENT_TEST_FAIL. transport.Console is logging the error when a test fails but it is not passing the data to the log server.

This is my code inside the custom reporter

```
runner
 .on(EVENT_TEST_FAIL, (test, err) => {
   ddLogger.log('error', 'HELLO')
 })
```

Here's the code for ddLogger:

```
const httpTransport = new transports.Http({
  host: 'http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com',
  path: `/v1/input/${process.env.DATADOG_API_KEY}?ddsource=nodejs&service=PEPINO`,
  ssl: true,
})

const ddLogger = createLogger({
  level: 'error',
  exitOnError: false,
  format: format.json(),
  transports: [
    httpTransport,
    // new transports.Console
  ],
})
```

This outputs {"level":"error","message":"HELLO"} in Console but data is not passed to log server.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it so happens you have wrongly declared your transport, which should be

```
transports: [ new transports.Http(httpTransport), ... ]
```